# Is there a way to have a CSS style only for webkit?

Tags: css, cross-browser, webkit, gradient

I'd like to have gradient'd text. [This place](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/gradient-text/) says the following:

```
h1 {
  font-size: 72px;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#eee, #333);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}
```

I don't want to show the background part to browsers that do not support `*-background-clip: text` nor `color: transparent;`.

Is there any way to do this, short of PHP?

Comment: What part of that doesn't currently work?  In webkit browsers (not necessarily all browsers that support it!), it will do what you want.  In other browsers, it won't show it.

Comment: I just realized that background: -webkit-... wouldn't work on non-webkit. I'm stupid.